# Fine grain height calculation in Angular 6 possible, or should I resort to JQuery?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am making an Angular 6 app which creates an html based report.

The principal view consists of a single component:

```
<report></report>
```

I need to be able to scan the DOM and determine in which element exactly (ie: at the deepest level of the tree if that makes sense) the height of the report exceeds X pixels (say 1,000).

Once found I need to then be able to manipulate this element by inserting an element within, and also modifying it's css attributes.

Also, the solution needs to take into account the possibility that this element may or may not lie deep within an [innerHTML] div:

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

I have looked into ViewChild in helping to calculate the height of certain components, but it seems quite limited given what I need.

Any guidance on how I would start to tackle this problem natively within Angular 6 would be much appreciated.

The other possibility I have looked at is mixing some JQuery code into my Angular app, but I would like to avoid doing this before ruling out that there is no natural "Angular way" of doing it (I am still quite new to Angular 2+ so this isn't immediately clear to me, as are the consequences of trying to "mixin" jquery).

(P.S. The purpose of all this, if you are wondering, is to be able to simulate "page breaks" in the report).

Thanks!

Comment: At the end of the day it's all JavaScript.  Can you provide more info about the structure of your components and a sample of what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer without knowing exactly the structure of your app, but I would wholly agree that jQuery is completely unnecessary in an Angular app.

Angular already works to completely decouple the DOM from your code. The Angular docs also mention that you should not be manipulating the DOM directly as it can interfere with the framework.

A couple options:

You can attach a directive to an element and inject the `ElementRef` into it. This gives access to the native HTML element host. You can use this to get any of the element properties as usual, just not setting them.

`constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}`

For 'jQuery-like' handling of the DOM, you can also inject the Angular Renderer (tokenized as `Renderer2`). This provider has several methods of querying and interacting with the DOM.

```
constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, private _el: ElementRef) {
   this.dummy = _renderer.createElement('div');
   this._renderer.appendChild(this.dummy);
}
```

The Renderer can also parse nodes with the `nextSibling` method, which might work for querying multiple elements in a parent element.